# Why do I get Rails 7 Routing Error although route is defined?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes, railstutorial.org

I'm following the Rails Tutorial by Michael Hartl to build a tiny demo app. I'm stuck at the logout. This is my routes.rb:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :users

  get    "/login",   to: "sessions#new"
  post   "/login",   to: "sessions#create"
  delete "/logout",  to: "sessions#destroy"

  # Define your application routes per the DSL in https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

  # Defines the root path route ("/")
  root 'users#index'
end
```

This is the relevant controller action:

```
  def destroy
    log_out
    redirect_to root_url, status: :see_other
  end
```

This is the session helper defining log_out:

```
  def log_out
    reset_session
    @current_user = nil
  end
```

and this is the link tag in the view:

```
      <%= link_to "Log out", logout_path, data: { 'turbo-method': :delete } %></span>
```

[Screenshot of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vo20Y.png)

When I click on the logout link, I get this error. Expected behaviour: Log user out, redirect to login screen.

What am I doing wrong?

I don't know whether it's because of Turbo, or whether Turbo is even correctly installed. I've added gem 'turbo-rails' to the Gemfile and ran bundle afterwards without any effect.

Answer (score 2):

For me, adding the method: :delete worked along with data-turbo.

```
<span>
<%= link_to "Log out", destroy_user_session_path,method: :delete, data: { 'turbo-method': :delete } %></span>
```

Answer (score 1):

You were accessing the DELETE method route via GET. Have you run

```
rails turbo:install
```

You may want to change the sign out via GET instead of Delete in config/devise.rb

```
  # The default HTTP method used to sign out a resource. Default is :delete.

  config.sign_out_via = :get # <= change this from :delete to :get and remove the `method:` in your `link_to` helper
```

Here's the references:
https://github.com/hotwired/turbo-rails
https://github.com/heartcombo/devise/issues/5439

Comment: I have the same issue. This project isn't using Devise - it's following the rails tutorial book by Michael Hartl. I have run `rails turbo:install`. It throws:  
`Import Turbo`  
`File unchanged! The supplied flag value not found!  app/javascript/application.js`  
`Pin Turbo`  
`File unchanged! The supplied flag value not found!  config/importmap.rb`  
`Run turbo:install:redis to switch on Redis and use it in development for turbo streams`

Answer (score 0):

Check with passing method

<%= link_to "Log out", logout_path, method: :delete, data: { 'turbo-method': :delete } %>

or

<%= link_to "Log out", logout_path, method: :delete %>

Answer (score 0):

You can change `link_to` to `button_to`

```
<%= button_to "Log out", logout_path, method: :delete %>
```

It will be less magic but more reliable because not a link but form is used (in normal life, clicking on link is a `GET` request)